# Http Session is Null in AuthenticatedWebSession Wicket And Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, wicket

Environment:

```
<wicket.version>7.7.0</wicket.version>
<spring.version>4.3.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
<springsecurity.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
```

I have custom class from `AuthenticatedWebSession` like:

```
public class WicketSession extends AuthenticatedWebSession {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WicketSession.class);

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final HttpSession httpSession;

    @SpringBean(name = "authenticationManager")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public WicketSession(Request request) {
        super(request);
        this.httpSession = ((HttpServletRequest) request.getContainerRequest()).getSession();
        log.debug("Got httpSession: {}", this.httpSession);
        Injector.get().inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
        try {
            final Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
            log.debug("Username '{}' is {} auth with authorities: {}",
                    username, auth.isAuthenticated(), auth.getAuthorities());
            if (auth.isAuthenticated()) {
                // the authentication object has to be stored in the SecurityContextHolder and in the HttpSession manually, so that the
                // security context will be accessible in the next request
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
                httpSession.setAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY,
                        SecurityContextHolder.getContext());
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            log.warn("Failed login attempt due to exception!", e);
            return false;
        }
    }


}
```

Spring Security Config like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public SpringSecurityConfig() {
        super(false);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        final InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        manager.createUser(User.withUsername("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN").build());
        manager.createUser(User.withUsername("rudi").password("rudi").roles("USER").build());
        return manager;
    }

    @Bean(name = "authenticationManager")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                .and().addFilter(new SecurityContextPersistenceFilter()).securityContext();
    }    
}
```

Spring Application Config like:

```
@PropertySource({"classpath:/META-INF/rcommerce.properties"})
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Import({
    SpringSecurityConfig.class})
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public AuthenticatedWebApplication webApp() {
        return new WicketApplication();
    }

}
```

custom class from `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` like:

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
        super(SpringSecurityConfig.class);
    }

}
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <display-name>rcommerce</display-name>

    <!-- WICKET FILTER-->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>wicket.rcommerce</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>applicationFactoryClassName</param-name>
            <param-value>org.apache.wicket.spring.SpringWebApplicationFactory</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>applicationBean</param-name>
            <param-value>webApp</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>wicket.rcommerce</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- MDC FILTER -->
    <filter>
        <description>A servlet filter that inserts various values retrieved from the incoming http request into the MDC.</description>
        <filter-name>MDCInsertingServletFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>ch.qos.logback.classic.helpers.MDCInsertingServletFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MDCInsertingServletFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>MoreMdcServletFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.rudiwijaya.rcommerce.servlet.MoreMdcServletFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MoreMdcServletFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- SPRING REST SERVLET-->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>
<!--        <init-param> -->
            <!-- use just the root WebApplicationContext -->
<!--            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> -->
<!--            <param-value>org.soluvas.sanad.app.ServletConfig</param-value> -->
<!--            <param-value></param-value> -->
<!--        </init-param> -->
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- SPRING REST FILTER-->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>httpPutFormFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>httpPutFormFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- The SpringWebApplicationFactory will need access to a Spring Application 
        context, configured like this... -->
    <!-- SPRING CONFIG -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.rudiwijaya.rcommerce.AppConfig</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- LISTENERS -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>ch.qos.logback.classic.selector.servlet.ContextDetachingSCL</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- ERROR PAGE HANDLING -->
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404.html</location>
    </error-page>

    <!-- TIMEOUT -->
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

when I call `session.signIn`, got error like:

```
Root cause:

java.lang.NullPointerException
     at com.rudiwijaya.rcommerce.WicketSession.authenticate(WicketSession.java:60)
     at org.apache.wicket.authroles.authentication.AuthenticatedWebSession.signIn(AuthenticatedWebSession.java:66)
     at com.rudiwijaya.rcommerce.pages.LoginButton.doAuthenticate(LoginButton.java:132)
     at com.rudiwijaya.rcommerce.pages.LoginButton.onSubmit(LoginButton.java:165)
     at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxButton$1.onSubmit(AjaxButton.java:113)
     at org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior$AjaxFormSubmitter.onSubmit(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:215)
     at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1307)
     at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:976)
     at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:797)
     at org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.onEvent(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:171)
     at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:155)
     at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:601)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
     at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
     at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:241)
     at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:248)
     at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:234)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:895)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
```

The error (**it is httpSession is null**) in line:

```
httpSession.setAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY,
                        SecurityContextHolder.getContext());
```

What should I do, please?

Comment: `httpSession` is null session might be expired .

Comment: class derrived from AUthenticatedAplication, methods `newSession()`, `getWebSessionClass()` - can You include here?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have more than one web container nodes ? With session replication ?

As a general rule you should never keep a hard reference to the Http Session. Especially in Wicket applications! Because if WicketSession is serialized and then deserialized this member field will be `null`!

Better lookup the HttpSession whenever you need it, i.e. extract`((HttpServletRequest) request.getContainerRequest()).getSession();` in a method and call it when you need the session in the methods' bodies.

Comment: Thank you @martin-g, I am gonna try what your suggestion. And no session replication and just two wars in single tomcat...

Comment: If I read in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Spring+Security+and+Wicket-auth-roles, there is NO httpSession in ```MyAuthenticatedWebSession```, it is OK? Because in another examples like https://github.com/dmbeer/wicket-7-spring-security/blob/master/src/main/java/com/copperarrow/auth/SecureWebSession.java or https://github.com/thombergs/wicket-spring-security-example/blob/master/src/main/java/org/wickedsource/SecureWebSession.java, there is httpSession.

Comment: I removed httpSession and line:
```httpSession.setAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, SecurityContextHolder.getContext());```, is it OK as concept Spring Security & Wicket?

Comment: IMO there is no need of this. You can always lookup the context with `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()`. I don't have it in my apps.